# insert in and delete an element from structur containing another structure

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I have a structure which contains another structure, and would like delete an element from the first structure. the two structures are defined like this:
1** first structure:

```
struct Solution {

    Problem *_Problem;

    vector<Tour> _tour; .
    vector<unsigned int> length; 
    unsigned int nbrCleint; 
    unsigned int TotalDemande;
}
```

2** second structure:

```
struct Tour{
    vector<unsigned int> clientVisite;
    unsigned int demande; 
    vector<unsigned int> CostScenario;
    Tour(); 
    void clear();
};
```

And now i would like delete from structure "solution" an element; for exemple delete element where ***solution._tour.clientVisite=="some vector"***

how can I do this ? and how can insert an element with the same principle??

Note C++ < C++11

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution s;
for (vector<Tour>::iterator i = s._tour.begin(); i != s._tour.end(); ++i) {
  if (i->clientVisite == somevector) {
    s._tour.erase(i); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Solution {

    /// Remove every tour where the tour's visit array exactly matches visit
    /// @param visit is a vector of unsigned ints representsing locations
    /// @returns the number of tours removed
    std::size_t remove_tour_where_visit_matches(const std::vector<unsigned int> visit)
    {
        auto original = _tour.size();
        _tour.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(_tour), std::end(_tour),
                                   [&visit](const auto& tour)
                                   {
                                       return tour.clientVisite == visit;
                                   }),
                    std::end(_tour));
        return original - _tour.size();
    }

    Problem *_Problem;

    vector<Tour> _tour;
    vector<unsigned int> length;
    unsigned int nbrCleint;
    unsigned int TotalDemande;
};
```

> I don't have c++11 yet

Then use a custom function object:

```
struct equal_visit
{
    equal_visit(const std::vector<unsigned int>& l)
    : _l(l)
    {}

    bool operator()(const Tour& r) const
    {
        return _l == r.clientVisite;
    }

    const std::vector<unsigned int>& _l;
};

struct Solution {

    /// Remove every tour where the tour's visit array exactly matches visit
    /// @param visit is a vector of unsigned ints representsing locations
    /// @returns the number of tours removed
    std::size_t
    remove_tour_where_visit_matches(const std::vector<unsigned int>& visit)
    {
        std::size_t original = _tour.size();

        _tour.erase(std::remove_if(_tour.begin(), _tour.end(),
                                   equal_visit(visit)),
                    _tour.end());
        return original - _tour.size();
    }

    Problem *_Problem;

    vector<Tour> _tour;
    vector<unsigned int> length;
    unsigned int nbrCleint;
    unsigned int TotalDemande;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11, and I dont have C++11, and when i add your code in my structure, I have many exceptions

Comment: replace the lamba with an equivalent function object.

Comment: @Mouaici_Med You should make that clear in your question and add the C++03 tag.

Comment: how I can do this ? @ Richard Hodges

Comment: yes thank you @ Richard Hodges,,, I try your now code , but i have some problems and i try to resolve this problems:

**ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘r’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     bool operator()(const Tour  &r) const
**** ‘remove_if’ is not a member of ‘std’ 

I don't why i have this prblems

Comment: @Mouaici_Med when comparing vectors, order matters. So the items in both vectors need to have the same values at the same positions.

Comment: @Mouaici_Med in order to use remove_if you must include the header <algorithm>